# SSL Working fine how can I add in http to https redirection?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, centos6

Hi I'm having major problems with a server, SSL works perfectly WHEN connecting with HTTPS://..., I need to set up redirection from http to https.

This is my ssl.conf, Centos 6, with one IP address. SSL Cert set up with SANs. Would rather not use .htaccess.

```
Listen 172.21.11.48:443

NameVirtualHost 172.21.11.48:443

LoadModule ssl_module   modules/mod_ssl.so  
SSLEngine on  
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/httpd/mod_ssl/ssl_scache(512000)    
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/aether.example.com.crt  
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/aether.example.com-2048.key  
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/exampleca.crt  

<VirtualHost 172.21.11.48:443>  
  SSLEngine on  
  ServerAlias      "webmail.example.com"  
  DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/roundcubemail"  
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/aether.example.com.crt  
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/aether.example.com-2048.key  
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/exampleca.crt  
</VirtualHost>  


<VirtualHost 172.21.11.48:443>  
  SSLEngine on    
  ServerAlias      "cloud.example.com"    
  DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/owncloud"    
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/aether.example.com.crt  
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/aether.example.com-2048.key  
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/exampleca.crt  
</VirtualHost>
```

When connecting on http://webmail.example.com it errors with "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port". When I add another vhost on port 80 Apache fails to start. Any help would be gratefully received.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `SSLEngine on` in the top of your config - if you configure that outside of your virtual hosts, you're turning it on for every virtual host on the server.

To set up redirection to https, you'll want something like this in your port 80 virtual host:

```
Redirect / https://webmail.example.com/
```

Comment: Hey Shane thankyou - all our vhosts are ssl'd and right after I got this working I found ou Nginx was in the mix too - so the rewrites are handled there!